# Paroles de la chanson « Les Enfants de Toromiro » ?

Tags: grammaire, formulation, paroles-de-chanson

> [0:16](https://youtu.be/urjL3BB8msY?t=16) ... ??
>  Tu nous fais franchir l'espace et le temps,
> Comme dans nos rêves d'enfant,
>  L'aventure c'est devenir
> grand...
>
> [ Générique *Les Enfants de Toromiro* ]

---

- Quelle sont les premières paroles de la chanson et le reste est-il exact ?
- Dit-on « l'aventure c'est devenir grand » dans la chanson et manque-t-il un *de* ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It's quite difficult to get all the words of that song. This question is also more suitable to the [chat].

Answer (score 1):

1. Le premier vers semble être:

> Si loin de l'île de pâques Toromiro

2. Oui, il n'y a pas de *de*:

> L'aventure, c'est devenir grand

Comment: @EylaChu-Generis Oui, la chanteuse a une drôle de diction. J'ai beaucoup de mal a entendre le [k] de Pâques, mais *Si loin de l'île de Pa*, ça ne veut rien dire... Je suis ensuite tombé [là-dessus](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophora_toromiro) et je me suis dit qu'il devait y avoir un lien entre les deux (je ne connais pas le dessin animé). Pour moi, il n'y a pas besoin de *de* (*partir, c'est mourir un peu*), plein de "l'aventure, c'est + infinitif" [ici](https://www.geoado.com/participe/pour-toi-laventure-cest-quoi/)

Comment: Devenir grand, c'est l'aventure des rêves de l'enfance.

Comment: Ouais merci, je comprends le lien et probablement. Pour le _de_ je dirais même que je trouverais la phrase avec mourir inusitée avec le _de_, possiblement ambigue. Mais je pense que je vois _c'est de_ comme _consiste en_ et parfois ce qui suit colle ou pas pour une raison. Ici, probablement que j'ai une impression bizarre parce que je prononce _c'estd-devenir_ et je me dis que j'écrirais ça avec le _de_. Ou peut-être que le _de_ il se cache ailleurs, comme dans ta reformulation en fait.